# Google maps app works without wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, google-maps

So I have been using google maps in airplane mode. I only connect to cafe´s around Barcelona and once I have searched the directions. I leave any wifi in range. Shouldnt that mean my google maps no longer works? However, on the app, when I walk down a street or make a turn, the little blue dot seems to update where I am, regardless of the presence of internet connectivity...

If I try retyping a search or starting a new route without wifi, it says that it cant connect to server, which is expected.

My question is basically, how does it know to update once I have established a route?

Answer (score 2):

The blue dot is because of GPS and not because of WiFi. GPS doesn't require internet connectivity to work when it locks onto your position.

How does it know to update? When you go off course then the app will try and update your route with a new route(which needs internet).